# не двигается seekbar

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Есть код, мелодии проигрываются, однако `seekBar` не двигается в соответствии звуку, также при нажатии `pause` проигрывание останавливается, но если потом нажать `start`, то мелодия больше не воспроизводится, хотя я в pause просто ставлю плеер на паузу, не убиваю плеер.Пробовал использовать `prepareAsync`, но вылетает ошибка *`MediaPlayer: prepareAsync called in state 0`*. Подскажите где допускаю ошибку?

```
public class Activity_Player extends Activity implements Runnable, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private Button mButtonStart, mButtonPause, mButtonStop;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private String position_sound;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    public static final String EXTRA_IMAGE_URL =
            "com.just_app.mplayer_img";
    public static final String EXTRA_SOUND_URL =
            "com.just_app.mplayer_sound";
    protected ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);
        findView();
        getIntentPhoto();
        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(position_sound);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Activity_Player.this, uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void findView() {
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageArtist);
        mButtonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        mButtonPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPause);
        mButtonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    }

    public void startAudio(View v) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mButtonStart.setEnabled(false);
        mButtonPause.setEnabled(true);
        mButtonStop.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public void pauseAudio(View v) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        mButtonStart.setEnabled(true);
        mButtonPause.setEnabled(false);
        mButtonStop.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void stopAudio(View v) {
        stop();
    }

    private void stop() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mButtonPause.setEnabled(false);
        mButtonStop.setEnabled(false);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
        mButtonStart.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mButtonStop.isEnabled()) {
            stop();
        }
    }

    public void getIntentPhoto() {
        DisplayImageOptions op = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .build();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String position_image = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE_URL);
        position_sound = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_SOUND_URL);
        imageLoader.displayImage(position_image, mImageView, op, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int currentPosition = 0;
        int total = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        while (mediaPlayer != null && currentPosition < total) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }
            seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (fromUser) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш метод `run` нигде не вызывается, оттого и не выполняется код в нём. Вы вообще не с той стороны зашли. Вам надо просто повесить `OnBufferingUpdateListener` на плеер методом `setOnBufferingUpdateListener` и именно в нём устанавливать прогресс сикБару.

Comment: Можно узнать почему не в ту сторону? мне надо чтоб он бегал, но также чтоб я бегунком мог перематывать звук

Comment: @Сергей, это только вы знать можете. У меня вполне нормально работало. Перечитайте свой код... А перематывать песню надо в onProgressChanged, учитывая длину песни и максимальное значение прогресса в сикБаре.